# Manipulate login page code to connect via WCF

Tags: wcf, authentication

So I have browsed the web and not been able to find any examples. I have a login system that checks an sql database to make sure the information matches and then lets them in if the details matches those in the database. However, I am struggling to work out how to check the database Via WCF. I am new to WCFs and i have managed to insert into wcf, load data into datagridview from WCF and save datagridview into wcf. I am new so help will be great if anyone has any examples? Thank you

here is my code for my login system before WCF

```
 private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Optimisation;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"); // sql connection
                    sc.Open(); // open sql connection
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Username, Password from UserDetails where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'", sc); // select usernames and passwords
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // data reader
                    string Username = txtUsername.Text; // username
                    string Password = txtPassword.Text; // password
                    while (dr.Read()) //datareader
                    {
                        if ((dr["Username"].ToString() == Username) && (dr["Password"].ToString() == Password)) // if username and passowrd match those in database
                        {
                            new Menu().Show(); // show menu form
                            this.Hide(); // hide this for
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is invalid", "login error", MessageBoxButtons.OK); // show message box if password or username is invalid
                        }
                    }
                    dr.Close(); // close data reader
                    sc.Close(); // close sql connection
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is invalid", "login error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }

            }
        }
```

and here is what is in my WCF:

```
public DataSet SelectUserDetails()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WCFTest;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username,Password FROM UserDetails", con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: what kind of WCF server you are using, please share contact binding details. and what kind of presentation layer you have? is it asp.net/WPF/winform?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you will be doing

1. Host the WCF Service either using visual studio development server or in IIS
2. Now, in the WebApplication, add a service reference to this WCF service
3. Now, create a client for the service and then call the WCF service as follows using the client

   ```
   private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       {
           using(var client = new ServiceClient())
           {
               // WCF specific credentials go here, if any
               string Username = txtUsername.Text; // username
               string Password = txtPassword.Text; // password
               var result = client.ValidateUserLoginCredentials(Username, Password);
               if(result){
                  // Login succeeded...
               }
           }
       }
    }
   ```

The WCF Service will look something like this

> ```
>   public class UserWCFService {
>         public bool ValidateUserLoginCredentials(string userName, string password){
>              // Database call or  call to the data access layer goes here
>         } 
>     }
> ```